# Pull Queue leaseTasks is not returning any TaskHandles

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task-queue, pull-queue

I am trying to use [Pull Queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-pull) on Google AppEngine, here is the setup

- Users will create a task through my applications REST API

  - It then adds a Task to "`TEST_QUEUE`" (mode: PULL)
- A Cron job will check the `QueueStatistics` to see if there are any pending tasks, and calculates number of workers to start and pushes the worker config (lease, number of tasks to fetch etc) to a [Push Queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push)
- In the Push Queue handler, i am doing some sanity checks and the issuing a `leaseTasks` Java API call

  - Here is the problem, this call is always returning empty array of TaskHandles.

I am testing this on AppEngine infrastucture and only 1 handler is attempting to `leaseTasks`

This is how I am adding the task

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("TEST_QUEUE");
TaskOptions options = TaskOptions.Builder.withMethod(TaskOptions.Method.PULL)
                                 .payload("Test");
```

This is how i am trying to fetch the tasks

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("TEST_QUEUE");
Logger.info("Task Count (Before): " + queue.fetchStatistics().getNumTasks());
List<TaskHandle> handles = queue.leaseTasks(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 100);
Logger.info("Task Count (After): " + queue.fetchStatistics().getNumTasks());
Logger.info("Handles: " + handles);
```

I have 3 tasks in the "TEST_QUEUE" (confirmed this from the admin console as well)

```
Task Count (Before): 3
Task Count (After): 3
Handles: []
```

After this, the tasks no longer exist when i check in the admin console. I am wondering if someone seen this before or am i doing something wrong? Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... after a few trial and error attempts, i found the issue

The following was my `queue.xml` snippet for the queue mentioned above.

```
<queue>
    <name>TEST_QUEUE</name>
    <mode>pull</mode>
    <retry-parameters>
        <task-retry-limit>0</task-retry-limit>
    </retry-parameters>
</queue>
```

The problem was fixed after `<retry-parameters>` was removed from the above snippet. I was trying to convert this queue from a Push queue, so i neglected to remove this since [Java Task Queue Configuration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/queue) doesn't mention that this parameter is only for Push Queue

Hope this helps someone :)